# Can you do batch pull messages with Google Pub Sub?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

Trying to optimize our application but doing batch pulling. Pub Sub seems to allow asynchronously pulling one message at a time with different client nodes, but is there no way for a single node to do a batch pull from pub sub?

Both Streaming Pull and Pull RPC both only allow the subscriber to consume one message at a time. Right now, it looks like we would have to pull one message at a time and do application level batching.

Any insight would be helpful. Pretty new to this GCP in general.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The underlying pull and streaming pull operations can receive batches of messages in the same response. The [Cloud Pub/Sub client library](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull#streamingpull), which uses streaming pull, breaks these batches apart and hands them to the provided user callback one at a time. Therefore, you need not worry about optimizing the underlying receiving of messages.

If your concern is optimizing the subscriber code at the application level, e.g., you want to batch writes into a database, then you have a couple of options:

1. Use [Pull](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull#synchronous_pull) directly, which allows one to process all of the messages in a batch at a time. Note that using pull effectively requires many simultaneously outstanding pull requests and replacing requests that return with new requests immediately.
2. In your user callback, re-batch messages and once the batch reaches a desired size (or you've waited a sufficient amount of time to fill the batch), process all of the messages together and then ack them.

Comment: Thank you for your response! We are indeed trying to lower the amount of transactions to the DB and therefore, i think we will have to perform application level batching through the user callback.

Answer (score 0):

You probably can implement that by using Dataflow (Apache Beam).  You can have a running streaming job, where you group, window, transform messages according to your requirements. The results of processing can be saved in batches or steam further. It probably makes sense in case the number of messages is really big.